# How do I protect myself against radioactivity?

Tags: stalker-clear-sky

I am the "open world lover, run & gun and watch the scenery when I'm at it" type of player, but I also find myself exposed to radioactivity most of the time.

How do I protect myself against it? Are there better suits or artifacts?
The suit I am wearing right now has 8 protection against radiation (and what does that mean, anyway?).
Also, I currently have an artifact equipped that has radioactivity: 1 and psy: 1, is that good or bad? I have the feeling I get radiated more since I equipped it.

Can I be immune or resistant to radioactivity, and which gear would give me that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must wear artifacts that reduce radiation to counteract the effects of artifacts with emit radiation.  Even if you have a suit with a high level of radiation protection, you will still get radiation poisoning if you only wear artifacts that emit radiation.

You can't completely resist radiation, but wearing artifacts that reduce radiation and wearing a good suit will greatly reduce the threat of radiation poisoning.

Here are the artifacts that can reduce radiation and their typical locations:

- **Jellyfish** (-2 radiation) in the Springboard
  anomalies
- **Wrenched** (-4 radiation) in the Vortex
  anomalies
- **Shell** (-6 radiation) in the Fruit Punch
  anomalies (you can almost always find one in the Fruit Punch anomaly in Yantar)

Comment: Drat. My only artifact has +1 Radiation, so it's blasting me along.. That's just sad :(